# Знак вопроса в конце сложноподчиненного предложения

Tags: пунктуация

"Спустя мгновение и старый пес учуял запах и вскочил, стараясь определить, откуда он?"

Всегда интересовало, в подобных повествовательных предложениях ставится точка или знак вопроса?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Розенталь:

Вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если придаточное предложение содержит в себе прямой вопрос, например: Всякого рода нарушения, уклонения, отступления от правил приводили его в уныние, хотя, казалось бы, какое ему дело? (Чехов).

Примечание. Если придаточное предложение образует косвенный вопрос, то в конце сложноподчиненного предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится, например: Не знаю, сколько времени я пробыл в этом положении (Л Толстой); Ты не сказала нам, почему не ходишь в училище (Федин). Постановка вопросительного знака после предложения с косвенным вопросом встречается, если последний содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, например: Не понимаю, что тебе нужно? (Чехов); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (Горький).

Тогда, выходит, и в предложении

"Спустя мгновение и старый пес учуял запах и вскочил, стараясь определить, откуда он?"

проблему, ставить ли вопросительный знак, решает автор в зависимости от интонации?

Answer (score 7):

Здесь не может быть вопросительного знака. Видимо, автор оказался настойчивее корректора. Вместо последней запятой можно было бы поставить двоеточие - тогда в конце уместен желанный знак вопроса (которым задаётся пёс). В этом случае "определить" стилистически лучше заменить на "понять".

Answer (score 3):

Само предложение не является вопросительны в чистом виде, еще его можно продолжить -откуда он взялся. Тогда проблемы отпадут сами собой. В противном случае используйте прямую речь, если вам кажется, что пес якобы от собственного лица излагает ваши мысли.

Comment: @petro это не мой текст, а цитата из книги советского издания. Мне интересна пунктуация именно в этом случае: можно/ нужно или нельзя/ненужно. Склоняюсь, что знак вопроса не нужен, но хотелось бы услышать подтверждение/опровержение.

Answer (score 3):

Розенталь и Добромыслов на подобный вопрос отвечали  когда-то так ("Трудные вопросы грамматики и правописания". М., 1960):

> **По существующим правилам**
> вопросительный знак ставится только
> после прямого вопроса (см. "Правила
> русской орфографии и пунктуации", стр.
> 104, § 180). Поэтому в предложении *Я
> спросила довольно некстати, по делам
> ли он заехал в нашу сторону* мы бы
> **сейчас** поставили на конце точку.

Для справки: у Пушкина в конце этого предложения стоял вопросительный знак.

Comment: В рукописи - тоже? :)

Comment: Alex_ander: "В рукописи - тоже? :)"=== Не знаю. Может быть, в рукописи и не стояло вопр. знака. Может, он явился результатом работы корректора. У Пушкина же ведь в рукописях очень своеобразная пунктуация была... См.:
-- Кто этот Валериан, спросил встревоженный старик. Неужели тот сирота стрелецкий сын что воспитывался у тебя в доме, Он сам отвечал Гавр. Аф., на беду мою. Отец его во время бунта спас мне жизнь и чорт меня догадал принять его в свой дом проклятого волчонка. Когда тому два года, по его просьбе, записали его в полк. 
(Пример из книги Шапиро "Основы русской пунктуации". М., 1955)

Answer (score -1):

Очень корявое предложение. Надо убрать "и": "Спустя мгновение старый пес учуял...."

Comment: Нет, не нужно. Оно вполне соответствует контексту. Сначала учуял один, потом другой, а, затем, и старый пёс. Кроме того, это совсем не имеет отношения к вопросу.