# Воспросительный знак в сложноподчиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, спп

Помогите, пожалуйста, выбрать правильную расстановку знаков препинания, с объяснением. Можно ли ставить двоеточие в таком предложении и нужен ли знак вопроса?

1. Они прищуривались и спрашивали его: не разведчик ли он?
2. Они прищуривались и спрашивали его, не разведчик ли он?
3. Они прищуривались и спрашивали его, не разведчик ли он.

Comment: Похожий вопрос: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/47368/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0/47371

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Двоеточие здесь неуместно, так как передается косвенная речь.

[Валгина, Розенталь. 363. Косвенная речь](http://pedlib.ru/Books/6/0262/6_0262-589.shtml#book_page_top):
Косвенная речь - это передача чужого высказывания в форме придаточного предложения... При отсутствии в прямой речи вопросительных местоименных слов косвенный вопрос выражается при помощи частицы *ли* в роли союза, например: Генерал осведомился, не сын ли я Андрея Петровича Гринева (П.). (Ср.: Генерал осведомился: «Вы сын Андрея Петровича Гринева?» или «Не сын ли вы Андрея Петровича Гринева?»).

Вообще-то говоря, знак вопроса здесь тоже неуместен, так как придаточное не содержит прямого вопроса.

**Они прищуривались и спрашивали его, не разведчик ли он.**

Но если Вы хотите предать сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, то знак вопроса можно поставить:

**Они прищуривались и спрашивали его, не разведчик ли он?**

[Розенталь. §76. Вопросительный знак:](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/41.htm)
2.      Вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если придаточное предложение содержит в себе прямой вопрос, например: Всякого рода нарушения, уклонения, отступления от правил приводили его в уныние, хотя, казалось бы, какое ему дело? (Чехов).
Примечание. Если придаточное предложение образует косвенный вопрос, то в конце сложноподчиненного предложения вопросительный знак обычно не ставится, например: Не знаю, сколько времени я пробыл в этом положении (Л Толстой); Ты не сказала нам, почему не ходишь в училище (Федин). Постановка вопросительного знака после предложения с косвенным вопросом встречается, если последний содержит сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию, например: Не понимаю, что тебе нужно? (Чехов); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (Горький).

Comment: Спасибо, очень чёткий, ясный ответ!

Answer (score 1):

Здесь не может быть прямой речи (соответственно, и двоеточия), поскольку вопрос, адресованный "ему", должен содержать обращение (т. е. текст вопроса должен быть во втором лице, а не в третьем), а с запятой (косвенная речь) здесь возможен только третий вариант - без знака вопроса. Чтобы поставить двоеточие, текст должен быть другим, например:

> Они прищуривались и задавались вопросом: не разведчик ли он?